# Acents become interrogation marks in php when parsing html

Tags: php, utf-8, html-parsing

i'm getting a PT-BR text automatically from downloading a html page and the acentution becomes interrogation marks when I use uft8_decode, this is my function:

```
function pegaMsg($string)
{
$bot_url = "http://website.com";
//&rnd=&msg="
$rand_msg = rand(0,100);
$url = $bot_url . $rand_msg . "&msg=" . $string;
$url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url);
//echo "\n" . $url;
$download = http_get($url, $referer="");
$download['FILE'] = utf8_decode($download['FILE']);
$download['FILE'] = str_replace("var resp = ", "", $download['FILE']);
$download['FILE'] = str_replace("\\r\\n", "", $download['FILE']);
$download['FILE'] = str_replace(";", "", $download['FILE']);
$download['FILE'] = str_replace("\'", "", $download['FILE']);

$download['FILE'] = trim($download['FILE']);
return $download['FILE'];
}
```

this is the output expected:

> VOCÊ TINHA DUAS ESCOLHAS:

and this is what I get:

> 'VOC? TINHA DUAS ESCOLHAS:

what can I do ? I want the ^ displayed ! thanks and sorry for the bad english

Comment: You might need to add "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">" to your html <head> section.

Comment: I don't have a html <head> section, it's a console program

Comment: on a side note: you can use an array in `str_replace(array("var resp = ","\\r\\n",";","\'"), "", $download['FILE']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8_decode` replaces invalid code unit sequences `?`. The reason you're getting a `?` is likely because the text you're passing to `utf8_decode` was not in UTF-8 to begin with.

In fact, it's possible it was already in ISO-8859-1, which is the encoding of the string returned by `utf8_decode`. In that case, your solution would be to just omit the call to `utf8_decode`.

If the original text was neither in UTF-8 nor in ISO-8859-1 (which is what I'm assuming you want, since you're calling `utf8_decode`), you have to use [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) or [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding).

A final possibility is that whatever is interpreting the script output is assuming the encoding of the script output is different from what it actually and it also converts invalid code unit sequences to `?`.

Comment: it's the windows cmd.exe, what do you think ?

Comment: if I omit the utf8_decode these are the kind of things that I get:
TUDO BEM COM VOC╩? instead of TUDO BEM COM VOCÊ?,  ├â┬ë BOM N├â┬ë? instead of ATÉ É BOM NÃO É ?

Comment: @André You must set the correct codepage and use a font that can display those characters. Write `chcp 1252` (Windows-1252 is similar to ISO-8859-1) before running the PHP script. The codepage for UTF-8 is 65001.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `encode`

```
$download['FILE'] = utf8_encode($download['FILE']);
```